# Mysql select data where userid and clickid no exist

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to do a php click mission. I need to mysql loop title and url when condition.

my condition is (show the `t2.title,t2.url`) if `userid` and `t2.id` does not exist in table `click_log` when `t2.clickdate = $todaydate`.

I have 2 table, first is `click_log` AS `t1`

```
+--------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
| ID     | uid       | clickdate      | clickid       |
+--------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
| 1      | 1         | 1452009600     | 1             |
| 2      | 1         | 1452009600     | 2             |
| 3      | 1         | 1452009600     | 3             |
| 4      | 1         | 1452096000     | 1             |
| 5      | 1         | 1452096000     | 2             |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

`t1.clickdate` is GMT+8 `timestamp` , `t1.clickid` = `t2.id`

Second table is `click_title` AS `t2`

```
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+------------+
| ID      | title   | url          | status      | other      |
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+------------+
| 1       | Helo    | http://xxx   | 1           |            |
| 2       | World   | http://www   | 1           |            |
| 3       | Good    | http://ggg   | 1           |            |
| 4       | Morning | http://aaa   | 2           |            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My coding defined:

```
$_G['timestamp'] = time(); //my server is GMT+8
$todaydate = date("Y-m-d",($_G['timestamp'])); //output 2016-01-07
$todaytimestamp = strtotime($todaydate); //output 1452096000
$_G['uid'] = intval($_GET['userid']); //this is user id
```

I query like this:

```
$queryJN = DB::query("SELECT t1.*,t2.title,t2.url FROM ".DB::table('click_log')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('click_title')." t2 ON (t1.clickid = t2.id) WHERE (how to write the codition?)");
while($rowJN = DB::fetch($queryJN)){
    $jn_list[] = $rowJN;
}
```

I try something like:

```
$queryJNbux = DB::query("SELECT t1.*,t2.title,t2.url FROM ".DB::table('click_log')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('click_title')." t2 ON (t1.clickid = t2.id) WHERE $_G[uid] IS NULL AND t2.id IS NULL AND t2.status = '1' AND t1.clickdate != '$todaydate'");
```

But cant works, suppose will display `t1.id` 3 `title` and `url` because `t1.id 3` does not exist in `t1.clickid` when `t1.clickdate` is `1452096000`

For safety issue, `DB::query` does not able to do `select * from` twice in 1 query. Please help me without do `select * from` twice or more, Thank you.

Yesterday whole day I was think about other way, after that I try to use `DB::fetch`, and it works, but I don't know is it safe for the query, or may cause another problem or not. Maybe someone can improve this query.

```
$queryJN = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('click_title')." WHERE status = '1'");
while($rowJN = DB::fetch($queryJN)){
    $rowexisting = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('click_log')." WHERE uid = '$_G[uid]' AND clickid = '$rowJN[id]' AND clickdate = '$todaydate'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($rowexisting) == '0'){
        $jn_list[] = $rowJN;
    };
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the mysql function `NOT IN()`

Comment: `$_G['timstamp']` shoulnd't be `$_G['timestamp']`?

Comment: @Matt Hi, I try `$queryJN = DB::query("SELECT t1.*,t2.title,t2.url FROM ".DB::table('click_log')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('click_title')." t2 ON (t1.clickid = t2.id) WHERE t1.clickdate != '$todaydate' AND t2.status = '1' AND '$_G[uid]' NOT IN (t1.uid) AND t2.id NOT IN (t1.clickid)");` but still cant work :(
@AdamBieńkowski I edit already, thank you.

Comment: You need to write subquery for this

Comment: Can u tried cross join ? : `SELECT t1.*,t2.title,t2.url from click_log t1 , click_title t2 where '$_G[uid]' != t1.uid and  t2.id != t1.clickid;` (Add another required where conditions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query ...

I have used here `NOT IN` and `EXISTS` in order to implement your conditions....

```
SELECT t2.title,t2.url 
FROM ".DB::table('click_log')." t1 JOIN ".DB::table('click_title')." t2      
WHERE $_G[uid]!=t2.uid AND t2.ID!=t1.ID AND t1.clickdate ='$todaydate'
```

I have updated my query as you can see no nested queries here.

There are many ways to write subqueries.

But hope this one may solves your query.

Comment: Hi, sorry the fuction of my `DB:query` do not allow I do more than 1 time of function `select * from` in 1 query. So I cant try your answer..

Comment: i.e. you are not allowed to use `select`   inside    `select`??

Comment: yes, system will display "this is not safe for this query"

Comment: When you write subqueries, I was thinking about is it other way to do 2 query to match my condition, then I try the coding it works, but I don't know will cost any other incoming problem or not.. maybe you can help me to check with it? I already edit the question in my last paragraph, thank you.

Comment: Please see my updated code...let me know if problem persists...sorry for late reply....

Answer (score 0):

You can use WHERE it is NULL as long as your column is allowed to be NULL.
you are pulling data from 2 tables so no RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN. You can just use JOIN or INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.title, t2.url
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.clickid = t2.ID
WHERE t1.uid = NULL AND WHERE t1.clickid = NULL
OREDER BY t1.clickdate ASC;
```

Or use COUNT, where the count of a certain column is 0

Select Count NOT NULL t1.uid

Comment: I have try `$queryJNbux = DB::query("SELECT t1.*,t2.title,t2.url FROM ".DB::table('click_log')." t1 INNER JOIN ".DB::table('click_title')." t2 ON (t1.clickid = t2.id) WHERE t1.clickid = NULL AND t1.uid = NULL ORDER BY t2.id ASC");` but can't work :( still no showing `t2.id` `3` title and url

Comment: I think your syntax is wrong! Your are trying this on laravel. have you got laravel installed. and you better read the documentation.
"WHERE t1.clickid = NULL" is not correct you should use 
"->whereNull('t1.uid')" ..... ALSO could you tag thi squestion with Laravel as well as PHP please. If you are happy with the answer could you mark it as correct please.